# using charAt() function assigning to the char array is throwing error

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, charat

I'm trying to save string in to a character array using the below code & im getting this error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to char[]

Below is the code

```
public class ExCaluculator{
char[] swi=new char[10];
String San="hello world" ;
int samsu ;
public void excal(){

for(samsu=0;samsu>San.length();samsu++)
{
    swi=San.charAt(samsu);
}   
}
}
```

Also please suggest me any other methods to do the same

Comment: What is unclear? You can not assign a `char`to and `char[]`!

Comment: You need to access the array with an index, like `swi[samsu]` or just use `String.toCharArray()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array` must be accessed with an `index` and you need a change in `condition` of `for` statement.

```
for(samsu=0;samsu<San.length();samsu++)
{
    swi[samsu]=San.charAt(samsu);
}
```

Also you have to increase the `array` size to `11` (`char[] swi = new char[11];`) in order to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Or Simply you can use

```
char[] xyz = san.toCharArray();
```

Refer: [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

ou have to assign the value to an element of the array:

```
public class ExCaluculator{
char[] swi=new char[10];
String San="hello world" ;
int samsu ;
public void excal(){

for(samsu=0;samsu>2;samsu++)
{
    swi[samsu]=San.charAt(samsu);
}   
}
}
```

Comment: There is not reason to do this by hand. As @Kayaman said `String.toCharArray()` should be the prefered way.

Comment: @SubOptimal there's a very good reason to do it by hand if you don't yet understand arrays and indexing and are trying to figure it out, as OP clearly is.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a `char` to `char[]`, array is subscript based. use something like

```
swi[0] = San.charAt(samsu);
```